# Can You Store Victory Crowns in Tents?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Fortnite Chapter 3 introduced some new and unique items and mechanics the game has never seen before. Victory Crowns and tents are two of those things included from the update. With tents you are able to store an item(3 max) for you to utilize in future games. Is it possible to store a Victory Crown in a tent? From what I understand, the crown is an item and it behaves similarly to weapons or consumables because you can carry it in your inventory.

Comment: AFAIK you can only store your currently selected weapon in a tent, so I don’t think so. But I can’t say definitively.

Comment: @Rup yup, that's what I thought, upon going in game and testing, that seemed to be the case. Thank you for the quick answer(maybe put your comment as the answer)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and tested this, and you can only put items such as weapons and consumables in your active item selection (what's on your main HUD) and this doesn't include items that cannot be removed such as your pickaxe.

The Crown works like bullets and materials where you cannot *use* them the same way you can with a weapon but it does drop upon death like bullets and materials.

[@Rup's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396482/can-you-store-victory-crowns-in-tents#comment556792_396482) also mentions this.